# Testing with dependencies via TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, dependencies, testng

I have these 2 tests:

```
@Test
public void Test1() throws Exception { ... }

@Test
public void Test2() throws Exception { ... }
```

I would like that `Test2` will run **after** `Test1`, and **only if** `Test1` was successful.

How can I achieve this in TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [`@dependsOnMethods` and `alwaysRun`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) properties like so:

```
@Test
public void Test1() throws Exception { ... }

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Test1", ..., ...}, alwaysRun = false)
public void Test2() throws Exception { ... }
```

Comment: [`alwaysRun`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#alwaysRun()) defaults to `false` so you don't even need to specify it.

Comment: You are correct sir. It is for clarification purposes :)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! @Idos

Answer (score 1):

You can also set test as `@BeforeSuite`, and in case of fail throw any exception - all pending tests will be skipped. It will also work with `@BeforeMethod`, `@BeforeTest` and `@BeforeClass`